# Grammar causing syntax error with valid input

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I am writing a lexer/parser for a simple programming language for an assignment and am having difficulties using Bison.

Flex file

```
%{
  //Definition Section
  #include "parser.tab.h"
  #include <string.h>    
%}
  //Rules section
%%
 
"START" {printf("Start Token\n"), yylval.symbol= strdup(yytext); return START;}
"END" {printf("End Token\n"); yylval.symbol= strdup(yytext); return END;}
"MAIN" {printf("Main Token\n");yylval.symbol= strdup(yytext); return MAIN;}
"MOVE" {printf("Move Token\n");yylval.symbol= strdup(yytext); return MOVE;}
"ADD" {printf("ADD Token\n");yylval.symbol= strdup(yytext); return ADD;}
"INPUT" {printf("Input Token\n");yylval.symbol= strdup(yytext); return INPUT;}
"PRINT" {printf("Print Token\n");yylval.symbol= strdup(yytext); return PRINT;}
"TO" {printf("To Token\n");yylval.symbol= strdup(yytext); return TO;}
[S]+ {printf("Variable Size\n"); return yyleng;}
[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+ {printf("Variable\n");yylval.symbol= strdup(yytext); return VAR_NAME;}
["][^"]*["] {printf("Text\n");yylval.symbol= strdup(yytext); return TEXT;}
[;] {printf("SemiColon Token\n");yylval.symbol= strdup(yytext); return SEMICOLON;}
[.] {printf("EOS Token\n"); yylval.symbol= strdup(yytext); return EOS;}

%%

yywrap() {}
```

Bison file

```
%{
%}

%union{
    char* symbol;
}

%token<symbol> START MAIN ADD MOVE TO INPUT PRINT END TEXT SEMICOLON EOS
%token<symbol> VAR_SIZE VAR_NAME

%start program
    /*Rules*/
%%

program:
    START EOS  
|   START EOS variable_declaration {printf("Start")};
variable_declaration:
    VAR_SIZE VAR_NAME EOS {printf("Variable declared")};

%%

int main(){
    yyparse();

    return 0;
}


int yyerror(char* s){
    printf("Error: %s", s);
    return 0;
}
```

For the first line of the input the line has to be START. after that follows the variable declarations. Variables have two strings one for the variable size which is just a series of 'S' and a variable identifier.

From what I have so far I would expect an input like:

START.
SSS XY-1.
SSSS Z.

To be a valid input. My problem is I don't know how to handle the order of grammar rules, in what way should the program rule move to the variable declaration rule?

Comment: `[S]+ {printf("Variable Size\n"); return yyleng;}`? Why are you returning the lexeme length as a token? That makes no sense.

Comment: The length of that token determines the value of the variable like SSSS can be a four digit value SSSSS a five digit value etc.

Comment: And what happens when these values start to collide with the values for the other tokens? And how would you even recognize such a sequence in the parser, since there's no fixed token? Instead use a normal token, and then pass the length as a semantic value instead.

Comment: And there's no need for `strdup` in the lexer, the strings will be pooled. Using `strdup` will only lead to memory leaks. Why are you even duplicating the lexeme strings? If you have a token `START` then why do you need the string `"START"` as well?

Comment: I wasn't trying to duplicate the strings, I misinterpreted how flex passes tokens to bison. I removed the ````strdup```` and it fixed the issue with var_declaration, thanks. When you say pass the length as a semantic value is that passing the length using yyval to the unions in the bison file?

Comment: Okay that's good that one problem is solved. And yes that's what I mean. Add a new token `S` and  a new `%union` member `int count;`. Then in that Flex rule set `yylval.count` to the length and return the token `S`.

Comment: Thank you for that, I did it and can see the S tokens value. One last question, how do I handle multiple variable declarations? I assume the rule needs a recursive call. Something like this? ````variable_declaration:
    S VAR_NAME EOS {printf("Variable declared %d", $1)} | variable_declaration; ````

Comment: The common way is to have two rules: One for the variable declaration *list*, and one for the actual variable declaration. Like `var_decl_list: var_decl_list var_decl | var_decl; var_decl: rule_for_var_decl;`